# Prove $\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I found this in the beginning of a calculus book, so it should be solved with very basic techniques, but I really don't know how.

Comment: since $\frac{2n+1}{n}= \frac1{n}+\frac1{n+1}$, with the alternating signs you get a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite $\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}$ as $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}$, then an expansion of the series will show cancellation leading to the desired sum. This is called a telescoping series. More on this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series.

Comment: The alternating sign does not have any effect on the telescoping series?

Comment: @gbox the alternating sign is necessary for the telescoping in this case, since otherwise the terms would be all positive and there would be no cancellation

Comment: On the link from Wikipedia the limit is the same without the alternating sign

Comment: @gbox the terms in the link are $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}$.